# MS Graph API: is it possible to order mail messages by recipient(s)?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

To tell the truth, I am a bit surprised I've failed to google the answer (not for MS Graph API, neither for MS Outlook REST API) - it looks like I am the only one who is faced the task to order the mail messages (for example, in Sent Items folder) by recipient.

In the manual, I see [it is possible to order messages by sender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#orderby-parameter); I can request something like

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$orderby=from/emailAddress/address

or

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$orderby=from/emailAddress/name,from/emailAddress/address

But what with the recipients, which are actually an array (even 3 arrays: toRecipients, ccRecipients and bccRecipients)?

I've tried all API requests I could imagine, but got only errors. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please share the attempted queries.

Comment: Not sure how it would help, but still... I tried a number of more or less reasonable queries as well as a lot of obviously stupid ones. By more or less reasonable I mean queries that aware of "array nature" of the toRecipients. Since I hadn't found a proper syntax, I'd tried:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$orderby=toRecipients[0]/emailAddress/name

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$orderby=toRecipients/0/emailAddress/name

and even:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$orderby=toRecipients.0/emailAddress/name

and got a BadRequest

Comment: Thanks Igor. It helps avoiding duplicate effort. I will take a deeper look at this and come back to you.

Comment: Ok got a reponse, adding it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by collections is not supported. Maybe, if recipients are well known, you can [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) by them and do client side sorting. Not the most efficient but might do the job.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I suspected, but just failed to find some explicit statement. BTW, did you find this in some manual or you just tried to "hack" an API?

Comment: @IgorKrein this comes from MSFT Developer Care Team. Btw, for complex queries supported by MS Graph you can take a look at [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/build-advanced-queries-with-count-filter-search-and-orderby/). Also you can request a feature to be added trough [Microsoft Graph Feature Requests](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) which sparked some of the ones discussed in the first link.

Answer (score 1):

Refering this query: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/656200/graph-api-to-filter-results-on-from-and-subject-an)

Make sure properties in **filter** should also be in **OrderBy** Statment.

```html
api_endpoint = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$protocol=imap\
                 &top=10\
                 &$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2016-01-01T00:00:00Z and (from/emailAddress/address) eq '{filter_email}'\
                 &$orderBy=receivedDateTime DESC"
```